# App Engine urlfetch is raising exceptions when i think it should not be

Tags: python, google-app-engine, monitoring

I've written my first Python application with the App Engine APIs, it is intended to monitor a list of servers and notify me when one of them goes down, by sending a message to my iPhone using Prowl, or sending me an email, or both.

Problem is, a few times a week it notifies me a server is down even when it clearly isn't. I've tested it with servers i know should be up virtually all the time like google.com or amazon.com but i get notifications with them too.

I've got a copy of the code running at [http://aeservmon.appspot.com](http://aeservmon.appspot.com/), you can see that google.com was added Jan 3rd but is only listed as being up for 6 days.

Below is the relevant section of the code from checkservers.py that does the checking with urlfetch, i assumed that the DownloadError exception would only be raised when the server couldn't be contacted, but perhaps I'm wrong.

What am I missing?

Full source on github under mrsteveman1/aeservmon (i can only post one link as a new user, sorry!)

```
def testserver(self,server):
     if server.ssl:
          prefix = "https://"
     else:
          prefix = "http://"
     try:
          url = prefix + "%s" % server.serverdomain
          result = urlfetch.fetch(url, headers = {'Cache-Control' : 'max-age=30'} )
     except DownloadError:
          logging.info('%s could not be reached' % server.serverdomain)
          self.serverisdown(server,000)
          return
     if result.status_code == 500:
          logging.info('%s returned 500' % server.serverdomain)
          self.serverisdown(server,result.status_code)
     else:
          logging.info('%s is up, status code %s' % (server.serverdomain,result.status_code))
          self.serverisup(server,result.status_code)
```

UPDATE Jan 21:

Today I found one of the exceptions in the logs:

```
ApplicationError: 5 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/webapp/__init__.py", line 507, in __call__
    handler.get(*groups)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/aeservmon/1.339312180538855414/checkservers.py", line 149, in get
    self.testserver(server)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/aeservmon/1.339312180538855414/checkservers.py", line 106, in testserver
    result = urlfetch.fetch(url, headers = {'Cache-Control' : 'max-age=30'} )
  File "/base/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/urlfetch.py", line 241, in fetch
    return rpc.get_result()
  File "/base/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 501, in get_result
    return self.__get_result_hook(self)
  File "/base/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/urlfetch.py", line 331, in _get_fetch_result
    raise DownloadError(str(err))
DownloadError: ApplicationError: 5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

other folks have been reporting issues with the fetch service (e.g. http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=1902&q=urlfetch&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Stars%20Owner%20Summary%20Log%20Component)

can you print the exception, it may have more detail, e.g.:

```
"DownloadError: ApplicationError: 2 something bad"
```

Comment: The most recent "false positive" was at 7:04 EST just under an hour ago, and there are only logging messages i've triggered with logging.info() in the appengine log. I could try letting the exception go unhandled but i believe i tried that a few weeks ago and only saw the DownloadError exception message with little else. I'll try that again though right now, hopefully the exception triggers again tonight.

Comment: Updated the question with one of the exceptions that occurred today after i removed the exception handling. I had not seen ApplicationError: 5 before, apparently it means the request did not return within the limit for urlfetch?

Comment: yep exactly right... the fetch service may have occasional latency (assuming the target server is not the issue). you can set the `deadline` parameter to something like 60 seconds in `fetch()`

Comment: It appears the max for deadline is 10 seconds, which i'll try but i may have to look into doing async requests or use a separate library for the requests like httplib.

Thanks for the help! Shall i mark this answer correct?